Application Recovery and Restart (ARR) doesnt work after shutdown the PC but works ok after restart
My application uses Application Recovery and Restart (ARR) to handle the saving state and restart it when unhandled exceptions occur. ARR uses the Windows API methods to register, restart, and recover callback.
ARR works only (calls recover callback and rerun application after crash) after Windows is restarted. When I shut down my PC and turn it on, ARR no longer works. I can successfully register, but if an exception occurs, ARR will not call the recovery handler and rerun my app till the restart of my laptop. After the restart, the ARR starts to work without problems again.
Application flow model:

RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback
RegisterApplicationRestart
Check with the method GetApplicationRecoveryCallback if recovery registration was completed
Check with the method GetApplicationRestartSettings if recovery registration was completed
Wait 65 sec (ARR works only if the app is run for more than 60 seconds)
Raise the exception

Thanks for your time and help in advance.
Rafal
